# how to pass multiple DATES to TO_DATE in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to select multiple dates.And from the application i am passing a string value that string contains multiple dates how i can convert that entire string into dates using to_date or is there any other way?  i am not able execute the bellow query

```
select * from emp 
where start_date in 
  TO_DATE('11-Jan-15 20:30:00', '11-Jan-15 08:00:00', '11-Jan-15 20:00:00')
```

and i tried the bellow one also

```
where STRT_TIME IN 
  TO_DATE('11-Jan-15 20:30:00', '11-Jan-15 08:00:00', '11-Jan-15 20:00:00',
         'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
```

none of the things are working but if i remove the to_date it's working fine in DATABASE but from the application iam getting error?

can anyone please help me?

Comment: And the application error is? And your DB engine is?

Comment: error is java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string and i am sure this is happen because of i am passing string from application to DB.before execute i need to convert the entire strings into date while execueting the above queries i am getting the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an `IN` list of dates... so many calls to `TO_DATE`:

```
where STRT_TIME IN (TO_DATE('11-Jan-15 20:30:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('11-Jan-15 08:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('11-Jan-15 20:00:00','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'))
```

You can do the opposite: i.e. make `TO_CHAR(STRT_TIME, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')` and compare that to the `IN` list of strings - but this is not as performant on large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting your character literats into dates with `to_date` you might try to turn your date into a character literal with `to_char`:

```
select * from emp 
  where 
    to_char(start_date, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')
  in
    ('11-Jan-15 20:30:00', '11-Jan-15 08:00:00', '11-Jan-15 20:00:00')
```